# material-ui: modify component property with inline not working

Tags: css, material-ui

I want to modify the 'toggle' component property, so that when it is 'on' the color is green.  The default behaviour is the the 'toggle' 'thumbOnColor' is set to the 'palette' primary color (in my case 'redA700').

The docs suggest the following should work, but it doesn't:

```
    <Toggle
        defaultToggled={relay}
        label={localization.get("user_bracelets_relay")}
        ref="relayField"
        onToggle={par(updateRelay, component)}
        thumbStyle={{thumbOnColor:"green"}}/>
```

I have tried using just 'style= ...' inline, 'style' with a .css, specifiying 'toggle: ...' in my apps Theme (ie. where I define my modified 'palette'.  Nothing seems to work, no matter what I do, the default behaviour remains.  Ideally, I want the toggle 'grey' when not set, and 'green' when it is.

Is it in fact possible to change the theme of the 'toggle' material-ui component in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to define your own theme, then you can override the thumb and track colors. For more details, read the [theme documentation here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes). However, if you are feeling dangerous, you should be able to use the following snippet, but beware the track color would also need to be similarly changed -

`thumbStyle={{backgroundColor:"green"}}`

Also, you will need to provide different values for this based on the toggled state of the component.

**Update**
The older version of the documentation had a themed toggle, you may be able to find it if you dig deep enough in the [documentation source at github](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/e51ba23ab9613ac470dc0ea8f2a9b9d9bf6a6e3d/docs/src/app/components/pages/customization).